# Validate a NVARCHAR for 6 digits and a comma

Tags: sql, sql-server, validation, sql-server-2008

I have a NVARCHAR that looks like this '123456,789123,345678'. I want to validate this for only 6 digits and a comma and throw an error if it anything else (i.e. 123E45,12345,1234 is invalid).

I have SQL Server 2008 for all those who want to use STRING_SPLIT.

Comment: You shouldn't store data as comma separated values. It will only cause you lots of trouble.

Comment: Did you try anything before asking on SO? If so, what, and in what way did it fail?

Comment: @jarlh I an not storing them... I am using them to insert a few records.. This is part of a batch process :)

Comment: @underscore_d I tried to use the STRING_SPLIT to get individual values and then thought of check if each value is a number and length of 6

Comment: Split the string using a UDF, validate each part individually. Better yet, Avoid working with delimited strings altogether - use a table valued parameter to pass multiple values into SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

This is a *horrible* way to store values.  But let me assume that you have no choice.

You can use a brute force method, with a separate `like` up to the maximum number of repeating numbers:

```
where not (',' + col like replicate(',[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]', 1) or
           ',' + col like replicate(',[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]', 2) or
           ',' + col like replicate(',[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]', 3) or
           ',' + col like replicate(',[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]', 4) or
           ',' + col like replicate(',[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]', 5) 
           )
```

Comment: I am not storing this.. I want to use this and insert a few records :)